# convert hexdecimal array to char array in CUDA

Tags: arrays, cuda, char, hex

I have C++ CUDA project and I have error "identifier "sprintf" is undefined in device code"). sprintf() works with in host code, so how I can convert hex to char in a CUDA kernel?

C++ code:

```
//md5Hash - its unsigned char hexdecimal array with length = 32
char str[16][2];
for (int j = 0; j < 16; ++j) {
    sprintf(str[j], "%02x", md5Hash[j]);//convert by 2 symbols
}

//convert from array str[16][2] to array new_word[32]
char* new_word = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*32);
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    new_word[2 * i] = str[i][0];
    new_word[2 * i + 1] = str[i][1];
}
```

string_to_hex (i need a similar hex_to_string)

```
void string_to_hex(unsigned char* output, size_t out_size, char* input, size_t in_size)
{
    //example: string_to_hex(md5Hash, 16, "1c0d894f6f6ab511099a568f6e876c2f", 32);
    memset(output, '\0', out_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < in_size; i += 2)
    {
        unsigned char msb = (input[i + 0] <= '9' ? input[i + 0] - '0' : (input[i + 0] & 0x5F) - 'A' + 10);
        unsigned char lsb = (input[i + 1] <= '9' ? input[i + 1] - '0' : (input[i + 1] & 0x5F) - 'A' + 10);
        output[i / 2] = (msb << 4) | lsb;
    }
}
```

First symbols from arrays md5Hash[32] and str[16][2] (all symbols from str array will = "1c0d894f6f6ab511099a568f6e876c2f"). I want to convert uchar md5Hash hex array to char array ***without sprintf*** and other namespace std functions. I need to call it from CUDA *device*

[image: First symbols from arrays md5Hash[32] and str[16]

Comment: using `itoa` function with `radix` equals to 16, here samples  https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/itoa.3.asp

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/kernel.h#L605

Comment: @lupaulus identifier "itoa" is undefined in device code

Comment: @0andriy i cant include kernel.h

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implement-itoa/  Implémentation of own itoa

Comment: @lupaulus its C++ code, i need only C code. swap() from namespace std, i cant use it in C code for CUDA device

Comment: You can write your Own swap function, no need of std namespace

Comment: @lupaulus and this code convert char to hex (look at output), i need convert hex (unsigned char in my code) to char

Comment: @pmg this is a working example in C++, I can use malloc in C. it doesn’t matter

Comment: @Bishamon: Your understanding of C++ versus C in CUDA kernels is not correct. CUDA supports a lot of C++ language features in kernels. But it supports almost no standard library features, either C or C++. That is your real problem and there is no solution other than to write your own implementations. Basically, you get malloc, memcpy and printf, plus math functions. That is it

Comment: @talonmies yes, i cant use namespace std - that is problem. I have function string_to_hex (i will add it to question), so I think there should be a similar way to make hex to string (string = char *)

Comment: There is not, Either write it yourself or do it on the host.

Comment: @talonmies maybe someone faced a similar problem. 
I cannot do this on the host because I need to call a method from the kernel. Added string_to_hex in question

Comment: So what is your question? You want to know how to convert an unsigned char to a hex string?

Comment: @talonmies no, i have a hex array and i want to convert it an char array

Comment: That isn't a question in the same way that "I want a million dollars" isn't a question. What *exactly* do you want to know?

Comment: @talonmies I do not understand you, what's the problem? I just want to make a char array from a hex array, that's all

Comment: Can you please edit your example to show what the contents of md5hash are and what the resulting  character array is and what part of the conversion process you don't understand. The sprintf code you have posted appears to only convert the first 16 digits the md5 value in a 2 character hex string. Is that really what you want? Understand that there are not generic solutions on the GPU, so exactly what your code does and exactly what help you need are important. [SO] is a question and answer site. Telling us you need something isn't asking a question. Please help us to help you

Comment: @talonmies check it now :)

Comment: You wrote "all symbols from str array will = "1c0d894f6f6ab511099a568f6e876c2f"". That is the lower 16 entries of md5hash, not all 32, correct?

Comment: @talonmies i think yes, and one symbol md5Hash = str[i] (i mean md5Hash[0] after sprintf will be str[0][0] and str[0][1])

Comment: @talonmies Is it possible to convert the string_to_hex function to the hex_to_string function? operations should be similar. but i don't understand how to do it

Comment: kernel.h has nothing to do with your code. I showed you an implementation of what you need which is used in Linux kernel. You may easily extract and reuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you require exactly two things to achieve what you need:

1. Decompose an unsigned char input into base 16 digits (of which there always will be 2)
2. Convert the digits of a two digit base 16 number into a pair of ascii characters representing digits in hexadecimal.

The first step can be done like this:

```
__device__ __host__ void makedigits(unsigned char x, unsigned char (&digits)[2])
{
    unsigned char d0 = x / 16;
    digits[1] = x - d0 * 16;
    unsigned char d1 = d0 / 16;
    digits[0] = d0 - d1 * 16;
}
```

This will return the most significant base 16 digit in `digits[0]` and the least significant digit in `digits[1]`.

The second step can be done by simple addition of offsets to the two base 16 digits to transform them into the correct ASCII values:

```
__device__ __host__ void makehex(unsigned char (&digits)[2], char (&hex)[2])
{
    for(int i=0; i<2; ++i) {
        if (digits[i] < 10) {
            hex[i] = '0' + digits[i];
    } else {
            hex[i] = 'a' + (digits[i] - 10);
        }
    }
}
```

A complete example could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

__device__ __host__ void makedigits(unsigned char x, unsigned char (&digits)[2])
{
    unsigned char d0 = x / 16;
    digits[1] = x - d0 * 16;
    unsigned char d1 = d0 / 16;
    digits[0] = d0 - d1 * 16;
}

__device__ __host__ void makehex(unsigned char (&digits)[2], char (&hex)[2])
{
    for(int i=0; i<2; ++i) {
        if (digits[i] < 10) {
            hex[i] = '0' + digits[i];
    } else {
            hex[i] = 'a' + (digits[i] - 10);
        }
    }
}

__global__ void kernel(unsigned char* input, char* output)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        unsigned char val = input[i];
        unsigned char d[2];
        char h[2];
        makedigits(val, d);
        makehex(d, h);
        output[2*i] = h[0];
        output[2*i+1] = h[1];
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char md5Hash[32];
    for(int i=0; i<32; ++i) md5Hash[i] = 255-i;

    unsigned char* d_md5Hash;
    cudaMalloc(&d_md5Hash, 32 * sizeof(unsigned char));
    cudaMemcpy(d_md5Hash, &md5Hash[0], 32 * sizeof(unsigned char), 
    cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    char str[16][2];
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; ++j) {
        sprintf(str[j], "%02x", md5Hash[j]);//convert by 2 symbols
    }

    for(int i=0; i<16; i++) std::cout << str[i][0] << str[i][1];
    std::cout << std::endl;

    char* d_str1;
    cudaMalloc(&d_str1, 32 * sizeof(char));
    char str1[32];
    kernel<<<1,1>>>(d_md5Hash, d_str1);
    cudaMemcpy(&str1[0], d_str1, 32 * sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    for(int i=0; i<32; i+=2) std::cout << str1[i] << str1[i+1];
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Note all code written during a coffee break, and is extremely lightly tested. Use at own risk]

Compiling and running this:

```
$ nvcc -o hexconv hexconv.cu 

$ ./hexconv 
fffefdfcfbfaf9f8f7f6f5f4f3f2f1f0
fffefdfcfbfaf9f8f7f6f5f4f3f2f1f0
```

This appears to produce the same output as the `sprintf` based host code in your question.

Comment: It works for me! Thank you, I spent a lot of time on this. You helped me a lot.

Comment: I didn't know how to do this until 1 hour ago. And I started by googling "convert integer to hexadecimal". I then read the first link and wrote the code you see. I'm sure you can do the same too, if you want to understand how this works and what the other code you had does